# Prawn error “data must be a two dimensional array of cellable objects”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, prawn

I'm using the prawn gem for pdf printing, so I'm trying to show the result of a stored within a table but when I try to print the records inside the column it shows me the following message: Prawn error “data must be a two dimensional array of cellable objects”

this is my pdf code:

```
    class Product < Prawn::Document
  def initialize(product)
    super(top_margin: 70)
    @product = product
    line_items
  end


  def item_header
    ["ID", "Item Name"]
  end

  def item_rows
    @product.to_a.each do |foo|
     [ foo.each do |label, value|
          value
          "," unless value == @product.last
        end]
    end
  end

  def item_table_data
    [item_header, *item_rows] 
  end

  def line_items
      table(item_table_data)
  end

end
```

what returns to me @product is a hash like this

```
{"ID"=>"12", "Product" =>"AP", "box count"=> 10}
```

the name of the hash columns like "Product" or "box count" may change depending on the data thrown by the stored

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: This video will help you it's about convert Ruby html to pdf file gem 'prawn' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BW5zwqj37Lo&t=743s

Comment: What's in the `@product` instance?

Comment: `item_rows` does not do what you think it does. the return value is simply `@product.to_a` because `each` returns the receiver. I think you might be looking for `map`; however if you change `foo.each` to `foo.map` you will simply get `nil` or `,` because `map` works on the return value from the block. Take a look at that part of the code to find your issue. (Hint: `foo.join(",")`)

Comment: @MikeGorski I have updated my post, the product variable returns a hash

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally clear on what you want the table to look like. But if you are looking for a table that gives a row for each value of the product, this will work:

```
class Product < Prawn::Document
  def initialize(product)
    super(top_margin: 70)
    # @product = {"ID"=>"12", "Product" =>"AP", "box count"=> 10}
    @product = product
    # The prawn table method expects an array of arrays
    # this will give you a row in the table for each value in the product
    table @product.collect{ |label, value| [value]}
  end
end
```

Comment: thumb up for this: prawn table method expects an array of arrays